# Not displaying icons and not working inline editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want edit and save icons inline editable and others like add ,delete normal navigation.I have written following code

```
$("#list1").jqGrid("navGrid", "#prowed1", {
  cloneToTop: true,
  add: true,
  del: true,
  save: true,
  search: true,
  refresh: true,
  cancel: true,
  edit: false,
  view: true,
},
```

So I set edit and save as false.For inline editing written following code

```
$("#list1").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#prowed1", {
  add: false,
  edit: true,
  editicon: 'fa fa-edit',
  save: true,
  editParams: {
    aftersavefunc: function(id) {
      jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('setSelection', id, false);
    },
  },
});
```

However this is not displaying save and cancel icon. I am using FontAwesome icons. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Here, you did't specify any icons for save(fa fa-save) or cancel(fa fa-cancel).You have used only edit icon.

Comment: I have added but still not able to do inline editing.

Comment: Can you share your codes in js fiddle?